# Реализация консольного приложения - игры

Tags: c#

В общем и целом, есть задача: Написать игру, в которой участвуют n-игроков. Программа загадывает число от 1 до Y (любое целое число) - gameNumber. Игроки ходят по очереди, при этом в консоли происходит отображения хода игрока. Игрок вводит число, скажем, userTry, которое может принимать значения от 1 до 4. При вводе userTry оно вычитается из gameNumber. Новое число gameNumber при этом выводится на экран. Побеждает тот игрок, который первее всех доберется до 0.

Первым делом я представил участвующих игроков как одномерный массив типа string. Далее создал массив numbers, в которое записывается загадываемое число gameNumber. Создал отдельную матрицу для учета ввода userTry каждого игрока. Получается так, что [i+1] элементы не учитывают ход игрока №1. Т.е. как было изначально записано в массив число gameNuber так и осталось.

Представляю ниже код неудачного решения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, идею как можно решить данную задачку.

```
namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("В игре участвуеют пять игроков. Можно выставить пределы исходного числа");
            string[] players = new string[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < players.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Введите имя игрока №{i + 1} - ");
                players[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Таблица игроков:");
            for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Игрок №{i + 1} - " + players[i]);
            }
            Console.Write("Введите верхнюю границу разыгрываемого числа - ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Генерация случайного числа....");
                Random rand = new Random();
                int gameNumber2 = rand.Next(10, n);
                while (gameNumber2 >= 0)
                {
                    int[] numbers = new int[5]; //Представление исходных чисел как массива
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        numbers[i] = gameNumber2;
                        Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
                    }
                    int[] usersTry = new int[5]; //Представление ходов игроков как массива
                    for (int i = 0; i < usersTry.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Ход игрока №{i + 1} - " + players[i]);
                        usersTry[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        numbers[i] = gameNumber2 - usersTry[i];
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем заключается неудачное решение? Приведите входные данные, выходные данные программы и данные, которые вы ожидали увидеть. Опишите пожалуйста проблему более конкретней, чем "_ниже код неудачного решения_" :)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков В общем, допустим загадывается число 28. Игроки ходят по очереди:
Игрок №1 - 4. Результат 24
Игрок №2 - 3. Результат 21
Игрок №3 - 4. Результат 17
Игрок №4 - 2. Результат 15
Игрок №5 - 3. Результат 12
Игрок №1 - 4. Результат 8
....
И так до тех пор, пока число не обратится в 0. Тот игрок, который первым дошел до 0 - побеждает

Comment: А что если "_Результат_" будет < 0?

Comment: В чем вообще смысл игры, если тебе показывают это случайное число? Если люди введут это случайное число, то ничего не происходит никто не выиграл, никто не проиграл. В этом и ошибка? Что не выводится победитель?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Не, это число, которое загадывается, постепенно уменьшается с помощью ввода игроков (userTry). Побеждает тот игрок, который первым обратит число в 0 (ну, или <0). Я уже думаю просто пойти через проверку условию, постепенно сравнивая результаты ходов игроков. Правда, тогда решение будет не лаконичным (для меня)

Comment: Ага а проблема в чем? Что-то не выводит? Я просто не понимаю смысла вообще игры этой, если игрок введете INT32_MAX он выиграл сразу :) В общем есть случайное число от 1 до n. И 5 игроков пишут число, которое отнимается от этого случайного числа. И кто быстрее получит это число <= 0 тот и победил? Вам нужно вывести этого игрока?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Да смысла то особо нет) Просто практика) На INT32_MAX пока не смотрим, просто я не стал пока указывать границы ходов. Именно, необходимо вывести имя победившего игрока. Но проблема кроится именно в элементах массива. Т.е. когда игроки начинают вводить число, то значение элемента просто равняется i-элемент = gameNumber (загадываемое число) - userTry. Идея в том, чтобы последующий элемент массива равнялся [i-1] - userTry. И перезапись происходит циклично, пока какой-то элемент не станет равен 0.

Comment: А вам обязательно использовать массивы?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Нет, конечнно, можно просто вложенными условиями писать. Правда, если игроков будет больше 5, то код будет громоздким. Короче, сам себе головную боль придумал. Просто пойти через массивы мне показалось более приемлемо при большом количестве игроков. Для двух и трех игроков у меня вариант работает отлично. Там просто через вложенные условия

Comment: Типа игра в "очко", только наоборот? При этом "перебор" - победа, а количество очков для победы неизвестно. Что-то я ничего не понял. Ввели границу 100 к примеру, комп что-то загадал, я хожу первым, ввожу 100, и ура?

Comment: @aepot Ну, типо того. Да можно ввести 100 на данном этапе, но пока это опустим (просто я не писал условия для ввода пока что). Надо с помощью цифр от 1 до 4 дойти до 0.

Comment: А без этих условий не понятен смысл игры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример вашей игры с комментариями:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("В игре участвуеют пять игроков. Можно выставить пределы исходного числа");
        string[] players = new string[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < players.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"Введите имя игрока №{i + 1} - ");
            players[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Таблица игроков:");
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Игрок №{i + 1} - " + players[i]);
        }
        Console.Write("Введите верхнюю границу разыгрываемого числа - ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Random rand = new Random();
        //Индекс победителя
        int winner = -1;
        for (; ;)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Генерация случайного числа....");
            int gameNumber2 = rand.Next(10, n);
            //Загадываем число и выводим его :) чтобы 1 игрок победил сразу
            Console.WriteLine(gameNumber2);
            while (gameNumber2 > 0)
            {
                //Ходы игроков по очереди
                for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"Ход игрока №{i + 1} - {players[i]} : ");

                    //Игрок вводит число и мы сразу вычитаем
                    gameNumber2 -= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    
                    //Если победитель еще не определен и число <= 0
                    //то определеяем i-того игрока как победителя
                    //и даем другим сделать свои ходы
                    if (gameNumber2 <= 0 && winner == -1)
                        winner = i;
                }
                //Если победитель найден выводим его и обнуляем победителя
                if (winner != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Победил игрок №{winner + 1} - " + players[winner]);
                    winner = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

В начале ничего не менял, убрал массивы ненужные ну и дальше по коду видно :)